# How can i convert this SQL to Laravel eloquent?

Tags: php, oracle, laravel, eloquent

I have the following SQL

```
SELECT C.CUOCODE, C.NAME, COUNT(*) TOTAL_PAYMENT, SUM(P.AMOUNT) TOTAL_AMOUNT
FROM TAX_PAYMENT P
INNER JOIN TAX_CHECKPOINT C ON C.CUOCODE = REGEXP_SUBSTR(P.INVOICEID, 'R....')
WHERE DELETED = 0 AND TO_CHAR(TXTIME,'YYYY-MM-DD') = '2018-04-24'
GROUP BY  C.CUOCODE, C.NAME
ORDER BY TOTAL_AMOUNT DESC;
```

How can i convert to laravel eloquent, i have "Payment" model (table TAX_PAYMENT) with "paymentid" as primary key.

Comment: i'm intrigued whether `REGEXP_SUBSTR(P.INVOICEID, 'R....')`  can be done in eloquent. nevertheless, adding the `model` will be best to make the relations clearer.

Comment: [We're not here to translate code for you](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265834/354577). Have you made an attempt at his yourself? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I'm sorry, i just want to get the idea on how to do it with this kind of queries, so i can do it on my other queries. I've been reading the documents but the there are just simple examples.@Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DB::table('TAX_PAYMENT as P')
    ->select([
        'C.CUOCODE',
        'C.NAME',
        DB::raw('COUNT(*) AS TOTAL_PAYMENT'),
        DB::raw('SUM(P.AMOUNT) AS TOTAL_AMOUNT'),
    ])->Join('TAX_CHECKPOINT C', 'C.CUOCODE', '=', DB::raw('REGEXP_SUBSTR(P.INVOICEID,'R....')'))
    ->where('DELETED', 0)
    ->where(DB::raw("TO_CHAR(TXTIME,'YYYY-MM-DD')"), '2018-04-24')
    ->groupBy('C.CUOCODE')
    ->groupBy('C.NAME')
    ->orderBy('TOTAL_AMOUNT', 'desc')
    ->toSql();
```

output

```
SELECT
    `C`.`CUOCODE`,
    `C`.`NAME`,
    COUNT(*) AS TOTAL_PAYMENT,
    SUM(P.AMOUNT) AS TOTAL_AMOUNT
FROM
    `TAX_PAYMENT` AS `P`
INNER JOIN `TAX_CHECKPOINT C` ON `C`.`CUOCODE` = REGEXP_SUBSTR (P.INVOICEID,"R....")
WHERE
    `DELETED` = ?
AND TO_CHAR (TXTIME, 'YYYY-MM-DD') = ?
GROUP BY
    `C`.`CUOCODE`,
    `C`.`NAME`
ORDER BY
    `TOTAL_AMOUNT` DESC
```

Comment: @PhouvanhKongchansavath that is a typo, I had fixed it :)

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty way would be to use Eloquents select raw like:

```
 $result = DB::select( DB::raw("SELECT C.CUOCODE, C.NAME, COUNT(*) 
TOTAL_PAYMENT, SUM(P.AMOUNT) TOTAL_AMOUNT FROM TAX_PAYMENT INNER JOIN 
TAX_CHECKPOINT C ON C.CUOCODE
= REGEXP_SUBSTR(P.INVOICEID, 'R....') WHERE DELETED = 0 AND 
TO_CHAR(TXTIME,'YYYY-MM-DD') = '2018-04-24' GROUP BY  C.CUOCODE,
C.NAME ORDER BY TOTAL_AMOUNT DESC"));
```